# How to remove the white space in UITableview scroll in the iphone landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, landscape

In my **tableview**, I have disabled the default scroll in **portrait** mode. But when the orientation changes to **landscape** mode, i have enabled the scroll so that I can view the entire content of the table. But, a **white space** is visible before and after the tableview cells, when scrolled. So, can anyone tell me how to remove this white space in the default scrollview of the table in landscape mode?
I've tried using the **autoresizingmask**, as well as tried to **set the content size** of the table according to the landscape mode. Both didn't work and this is my code so far.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

{

    // Return YES for supported orientations

    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

  }

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){

        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

        self.tableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount =5;

       self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 320);

        self.tableView.autoresizingMask = YES;

       //CGFloat cellHeight;}

    else if((self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) || (self.interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)){

        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

        }
  }
```

Comment: have to tried to make the background color of the tableview as clearcolor ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method,

```
[self.tableView setBounces: NO];
```

It stops the scroll from bouncing and will remove the white space.

Answer (score 1):

set cell seperator to none & make background color as clearColor.be sure that scrollView style is set to Default.

Comment: Got it working by the above answer. If i set it to clearcolor, it makes the white space to be black. What i wanted was to remove the space, whichever color it might be. Anyway thanks for ur answer.